# Trying to draw a bookshelf (Khan Academy exercise)

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing

I'm doing an exercise that involves painting bookshelves on a canvas based on an array of book objects. The exact instructions are as follows:

> Now add more books, and use the loop to draw more shelves down the canvas. Think about how you can use conditionals and/or the % operator to do that.

My code includes a conditional in the loop but I cannot seem to get it to work. The conditional is at the very end of the code below.

```
//book array
var books = [{
    title: "The Giver",
    author: "Lois Lowry",
    coverColor: color(214, 255, 219),
    stars: 3
}, {
    title: "The Outsiders",
    author: "S. E. Hinton",
    coverColor: color(255, 127, 127),
    stars: 5
}, {
    title: "Harry Potter",
    author: "J. K. Rowling",
    coverColor: color(135, 193, 255),
    stars: 4
}, {
    title: "Harry Potter",
    author: "J. K. Rowling",
    coverColor: color(135, 193, 255),
    stars: 4
}];

// draw shelf
background(230, 187, 122);
fill(173, 117, 33);
rect(0, 120, width, 10);

// book loop
for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    var book = books[i]; //setting book variable
    var xPos = i * 100;
    var yPos = 20;
    fill(book.coverColor);
    rect(xPos + 10, yPos, 90, 100);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    textSize(11); //general book drawings
    text(book.title, xPos + 15, yPos + 5, 70, 100);
    textSize(9);
    text(book.author, xPos + 20, yPos * 2, 70, 100);

    //Seal of approval
    if (book.stars > 3) {
        var approvalSeal = getImage("cute/Star");
        image(approvalSeal, xPos + 10, yPos * 4, 30, 40);
        text("Seal of approval!", xPos + 45, yPos * 4 + 15, 50, 40);
    }

    //conditional wrap-around
    if (xPos > 350) {
        xPos = i * 100;
        yPos += 120;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put this outside the loop:

```
var yPos = 20;
```

Currently you're resetting `yPos` on each iteration, so the wraparound code never takes effect.

There's also a problem with `xPos`. You're setting it to `i * 100` on each iteration, which makes it go beyond the end of the shelf. You have to reset `xPos` when you make a new shelf.

A correct approach is to initialize `xPos` and `yPos`, draw the first shelf, then start iterating over the books. Increment the book position and wrap around if necessary:

```
function drawShelf(yPos) {
  var saved = context.fillStyle;
  fill(color(173, 117, 33));
  rect(0, yPos + 120, width, 10);
  context.fillStyle = saved;
}

var xPos = 0,
    yPos = 0;

drawShelf(yPos);

for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
  var book = books[i];
  fill(book.coverColor);
  rect(xPos + 10, yPos + 20, 90, 100);
  xPos += 100;
  if (xPos > 350) {
    xPos = 0;
    yPos += 130;
    drawShelf(yPos);
  }
}
```

You can see this code run in the snippet below. I've added code to emulate the drawing commands from the Processing environment and I've made a dozen book objects with random colors. The other book attributes are omitted.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0],
    width = 410,
    height = 400,
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
function background(r, g, b) {
  var saved = context.fillStyle;
  fill(color(r, g, b));
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.fillStyle = saved;
}
function color(r, g, b) {
  return 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
}
function fill(style) {
  context.fillStyle = style;
}
function rect(x, y, w, h) {
  context.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}

var books = new Array(12);
for (var i = 0; i < books.length; ++i) {
  books[i] = {
    coverColor: color(
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 256),
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 256),
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
    )
  };
}

background(230, 187, 122);

function drawShelf(yPos) {
  var saved = context.fillStyle;
  fill(color(173, 117, 33));
  rect(0, yPos + 120, width, 10);
  context.fillStyle = saved;
}

var xPos = 0,
    yPos = 0;

drawShelf(yPos);

for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
  var book = books[i];
  fill(book.coverColor);
  rect(xPos + 10, yPos + 20, 90, 100);
  xPos += 100;
  if (xPos > 350) {
    xPos = 0;
    yPos += 130;
    drawShelf(yPos);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Your code worked quite nicely! Khan Academy has a funny API so I had to play with the code a little to get it to work but once it was going it worked like a charm! Awesome job and thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason your conditional does nothing is because it is at the end of the for loop iteration. Nothing is done with the new values assigned, and as the next iteration rolls, the coordinates revert back to the "first row of books" coordinates. You need to assign these coordinates before using them.

The way I drew my (ugly) bookshelf was using only the % operator for the x-coordinate and floored division for the row. It seemed easier to me than using conditionals. The bookshelf can be seen as a grid, ordered like

```
0 1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 ... etc
```

Since you wrote `350` as the limit, I assumed you want to display 3 books per row. Notice that the x-coordinates repeat themselves, like this

```
0 100 200
0 100 200
0 100 200
```

The % operator, when used with positive arguments, returns a remainder of the first argument divided by the second. Using 300 as the second argument, I get the repeated sequence of 0, 100, and 200 for the x-coordinates.

Now, the row y-coordinates merely increase, every 3 books. So I use Math.floor to round down to the exact whole number of rows I want to jump to, and with these values, determine where to draw the book.

In my quick demo I have to rely on primitive canvas operations only. I am unfamiliar with the provided Khan Academy tools.

Also I don't think you mean to use yPos * 2 or * 4, because as you move down a few rows these offsets get multiplied, rather than merely shifted down.

```js
     var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

     function color() {}

     function fill(r, g, b) {

     }

     function rect(x, y, w, h) {
       ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
       ctx.stroke();
     }

     function text(s, x, y, w, h) {
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.moveTo(x, y);
       ctx.font = "9px serif";
       ctx.fillText(s, x, y + 15);
       ctx.stroke();
     }

     var books = [{
       title: "The Giver (0)",
       author: "Lois Lowry (0)",
       coverColor: color(214, 255, 219),
       stars: 3
     }, {
       title: "The Outsiders (1)",
       author: "S. E. Hinton (1)",
       coverColor: color(255, 127, 127),
       stars: 5
     }, {
       title: "Harry Potter (2)",
       author: "J. K. Rowling (2)",
       coverColor: color(135, 193, 255),
       stars: 4
     }, {
       title: "Mary Scooter (3)",
       author: "G. Q. Bowling (3)",
       coverColor: color(135, 193, 255),
       stars: 4
     }, {
       title: "The Brothers Karmazoov (4)",
       author: "F. Downstoveeski (4)",
       coverColor: color(214, 255, 219),
       stars: 3
     }, {
       title: "The Unbearable Brightness of Skiing (5)",
       author: "Milano Counter (5)",
       coverColor: color(255, 127, 127),
       stars: 5
     }, {
       title: "The Uber Gatsby (6)",
       author: "Scot-Free Fitzgee (6)",
       coverColor: color(135, 193, 255),
       stars: 4
     }, {
       title: "Catch-42 (7)",
       author: "Joe Keller (7)",
       coverColor: color(135, 193, 255),
       stars: 4
     }, {
       title: "Focker's Pendulum (8)",
       author: "Umbrella Ekoh (8)",
       coverColor: color(214, 255, 219),
       stars: 3
     }, {
       title: "The Tiny Princess (9)",
       author: "Anthony St. Expert (9)",
       coverColor: color(255, 127, 127),
       stars: 5
     }, {
       title: "Of Fire and Ice (10)",
       author: "George Martinelli (10)",
       coverColor: color(135, 193, 255),
       stars: 4
     }];

      // draw shelf
      // background(230, 187, 122);
      // fill(173, 117, 33);
      // rect(0, 120, width, 10);

      // book loop
     for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
       var book = books[i]; //setting book variable

       // DETERMINE WHERE TO PLACE TOP-LEFT BOOK CORNER 
       var xPos = (i * 100 % 300);
       var yPos = 20 + 120 * Math.floor(i / 3);

       // var xPos = i*100;
       // var yPos = 20;

       // fill(book.coverColor);
       rect(xPos + 10, yPos, 90, 100);
       // fill(0, 0, 0);
       // textSize(11);//general book drawings
       text(book.title, xPos + 15, yPos + 5, 70, 100);
       // textSize(9);
       text(book.author, xPos + 20, yPos + 25, 70, 100);

       //Seal of approval
       if (book.stars > 3) {
         // var approvalSeal = getImage("cute/Star");
         // image(approvalSeal,xPos+10, yPos*4, 30, 40);
         text("Seal of approval!", xPos + 45, yPos + 40 + 15, 50, 40);
       }

       //conditional wrap-around
       // if(xPos > 350) {
       //   xPos = i*100;
       // yPos += 120;
       // }
     }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="600">
</canvas>
```